# Unable to parse CSV with escaped characters in quotes

Tags: python, csv, parsing, double-quotes, reader

I have a series of CSV's that are badly formatted, and I am having some trouble parsing them using the CSV parser from Python's standard lib. Essentially, the CSV's are not escaping return characters, and I am getting some output that I don't understand.

It seems that the parser can sometimes get the proper lines together, but is dropping, or adding irregularly. For example, in the entry with id=1, the quote in the middle of the string is removed but the one on the end is kept. A similar thing occurs in the last entry (id=3). I would expect the outer most quotes to be dropped in the entry as with the ids.

It also is not combining the lines in a way that I can find to be predictable. The entry with id=2 is broken into two entries, and I cannot understand a pattern why the other two are kept intact but this one is split.

Is there some ambiguity in the format of the CSV's that I am not understanding that makes them difficult to parse other than the unescaped return characters. I have tried a variety of format params to no avail. Any clarity would be much appreciated.

To clarify, I understand that I can do string replacement before I parse the CSV's. I am asking why the output does not seem to be regular.

Code:

```
import csv

with open('text.csv') as csv_file:
    for line in csv.reader(csv_file):
        print(line)
```

Input:

```
"id","text"
"1","This line here
More Text "quoted"
"2","This line here "quoted" More Text
More Text "quoted" More Text"
"3","This line here
"quoted"
```

Output:

```
['id', 'text', 'id2']
['97910', 'This line here\r\nMore Text quoted"', '1']
['97930', 'This line here quoted" More Text']
['More Text "quoted" More Text"', '2']
['97930', 'This line here\r\nquoted"', '3']
```

Desired output:

```
['id', 'text', 'id2']
['97910', 'This line here\r\nMore Text "quoted', '1']
['97930', 'This line here "quoted" More Text\r\nMore Text "quoted" More Text', '2']
['97930', 'This line here\r\n"quoted', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

> Each of the embedded double-quote characters must be represented by a
>   pair of double-quote characters.

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"
```

> Fields with embedded line breaks must be quoted (however, many CSV
>   implementations do not support embedded line breaks).

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Go get one now
they are going fast"
```

So you can replace double quotes with 2 double quotes before you parse the csv file or try to write the csv file by escaping double quotes.

---

**Each line of the file is a data record. Each record consists of one or more fields, separated by commas.** But if you use double quotes it will find the corresponding double quotes, if the parser can't find it, it will read next line until getting a double-quote, and then, it can't find the comma so that's why it treat

```
"This line here
More Text "quoted"
```

as only one filed, for `"2","This line here "quoted" More Text`, the same reason, the parser can find a pair of double quotes, so it will read next record.

See more details from [Comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Comment: Right, I understand what I more strict csv would look like. I am more asking why one is being broken into pieces while the others are not.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the lines that I am perceiving to be correct are only incidentally being pick up by the parser because of the specific combination of quotes and in fact none of them are being parse in a 'correct' manner?